# AWS litespeed not launching, timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openlitespeed

I'm just trying to launch EC2 instance with open litespeed wordpress. Once everything is setup and the instance sayings running, the IP still loading and finally shows timed error. This happens only with the openlitespeed wordpress image.

Comment: I have two OLS WordPress instances on AWS and no such issue. Do you have this issue with default WordPress or did you migrate sites to the instance? If the issue is reproducible, maybe you can send the issue to bug@litespeedtech.com for further support. It's not easy to get answers from StackOverflow without any log.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something we as a community can fix but don't quote me on that, have you tried contacting AWS support and running through troubleshooting? That could fix your issue.

Comment: this seems to be more a comment than a solution.